# "warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in type name" when declaring const char*

Tags: c

I'm writing a very simple C program, which begins like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main( int argc, char **argv ){

  // check that the program has been invoked correctly
  if( argc < 3 ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Usage: find_char <string> <string>.\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  char const *source = (const) (*++argv);
```

For the last line, I get the following warning:

`main.c:17:3: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in type name [enabled by default]
   char const *source = (const) (*++argv);`

I tried:

```
char const *source = NULL;
source = (const) (*++argv);
```

but gives the same varning for the second line. What is going on here?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

casting to `const` amounts to casting to `const int`. When type is omitted and only qualified is set, the compiler just assumes `int`.

Just remove the `(const)` cast. You already did the right thing by declaring the pointed values as `const`.